# How does bytebuffer wrap work?

Tags: java

So i have coded something to test the ByteBuffer wrap function:

```
byte[] cArr = ..

System.out.println("cArr length is " + cArr.length);

ByteBuffer e = ByteBuffer.wrap(cArr, 0, cArr.length );

System.out.println("e length is " + e.array().length);

ByteBuffer d = ByteBuffer.wrap(cArr, 4, 8 );

System.out.println("d length is " + d.array().length);
```

This is the output:

> cArr length is 12
>
> e length is 12
>
> d length is 12

Why is the length of d still 12 even after wrapping and specifying length 8?

Comment: But you asked for the length of the underlying array..

Comment: ahh, I see. I thought that by wrapping, a new array is created everytime.  Thx!

Comment: The Javadoc even states as much: "The new buffer's limit will be set to offset + length."

Answer (score 1):

> Why is the length of d still 12 even after wrapping and specifying length 8?

Literally, because `d.array()` *is* `cArr`.

> **The new buffer will be backed by the given byte array**; that is, modifications to the buffer will cause the array to be modified and vice versa. **The new buffer's capacity will be `array.length`**, its position will be `offset`, its limit will be `offset + length`, and its mark will be undefined. **Its backing array will be the given array**, and its array offset will be zero.

Take the following snippet:

```
byte[] arr = new byte[12];
ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.wrap(arr, 4, 8);
System.out.println(buf.array() == arr);
```

which prints *`true`*.

http://ideone.com/bqDdDs

`ByteBuffer.wrap` does not copy the array, it just creates an object around the specified array which lets you work with the array directly.